# C++ what is the value category of *this?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, this-pointer

Section 9.3.2.1 of the C++ standard states:

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is
>   a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for
>   which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of
>   a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const, the type of
>   this is const X*, if the member function is declared volatile, the
>   type of this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared
>   const volatile, the type of this is const volatile X*.

So if `this` is a prvalue, what is the value category of `*this`? The following suggests that even when the object is an rvalue, `*this` is always an lvalue. Is this correct? Please refer to the standard, if possible.

```
struct F;
struct test
{
    void operator()(F &&) { std::cout << "rvalue operator()" << std::endl; }
    void operator()(F const &&) { std::cout << "const rvalue operator()" << std::endl; }
    void operator()(F &) { std::cout << "lvalue operator()" << std::endl; }
    void operator()(F const &) { std::cout << "const lvalue operator()" << std::endl; }
};

struct F
{
    void operator ()()
    {
        struct test t;
        t(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct F f;
    f();
    std::move(f)();
}
```

Output:

```
lvalue operator()
lvalue operator()
```

Comment: The result of dereferencing a pointer is always an lvalue. There are no "xvalue pointers" in C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB is that a consequence of the "if it has a name" rule?

Comment: @AmiTavory: There isn't such a rule. That's more of a rule-of-thumb, but that's not the formal specification. It's simply because the language says so. Essentially once you're able to obtain the address of something, you have have an lvalue. Note that you can't take the address of rvalues of builtin types.

Comment: If you use reference-qualified methods along with `std::move` you'll see a difference: `void operator()()&{(test(*this));} void operator()()&&{(test(std::move(*this)));}`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Interesting!

Comment: This can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [basic.lval]:

> An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment
>   expression) designates a function or an object. *[ Example:* If `E` is an expression of pointer type, then
>   `*E` is an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which `E` points. As another example,
>   the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue. *—end example ]*

And from [expr.unary.op]:

> The unary `*` operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an
>   object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an **lvalue** referring to the object or function
>   to which the expression points.

Dereferencing a pointer is an lvalue. So `*this` is an lvalue.

Alternatively, anything that isn't an lvalue is an rvalue. An rvalue is:

> An rvalue (so called, historically, because rvalues could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment
>   expression) is an xvalue, a temporary object (12.2) or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated
>   with an object.

And `*this` is definitely none of those things.

Comment: @Nik-Lz I don't understand this comment. What's strange, where does cppreference say that, and why would that matter?

Comment: @Nik-Lz How does that affect what value category of `*this` is?